# CreateProcess and get the handle

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-2010

I'm using CreateProcess API to integrate RealVNC with my exe... I just need to process handle for the created vnc client, but I'm unsuccess so far. The code is pretty simple:

```
procedure TForm1.VncAuth;
var
  StartInfo: TStartupInfo;
  ProcInfo: TProcessInformation;
  CmdLine: string;
  title: string;
  ProcHandle: THandle;
begin
  FillChar(StartInfo,SizeOf(TStartupInfo),#0);
  FillChar(ProcInfo,SizeOf(TProcessInformation),#0);
  StartInfo.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);
  CmdLine:= 'vnc.exe';
  UniqueString(CmdLine);
  CreateProcess(NIL ,PChar(CmdLine), NIL, NIL, False, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE or NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS
                                  , NIL, NIL, StartInfo, ProcInfo);
  ProcHandle:= ProcInfo.hProcess;
  GetWindowText(ProcHandle, PChar(title), 255);
  ShowMessage(title);
end;
```

Nothing is returned in title var... the GetWindowText function is just a test to see if I have the right handle, if Yes I should see the vnc client title's right?
Thank you!

Comment: `ProcInfo.hProcess` is a **process** handle. `GetWindowText` is expecting a **window** handle. They're not the same thing at all,  any more than a door handle is a knife handle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Window handles and process handles are not the same thing. For `GetWindowText` you need a window handle.

1. After creating the process call `WaitForInputIdle` to allow the process to start up and create its main window.
2. Call `EnumWindows` to enumerate the top level windows.
3. For each top level window, call `GetWindowThreadProcessId` to find out the process ID of the process that created that window. The process ID of the process you created is `ProcInfo.dwProcessId`.
4. When you have find a window with process ID that matches that of the process you just created, that window is your guy!

Comment: You might need to include a class name or visibility or etc.. test to the 4th step as many processes creates more than one top level window.