# How to show the content of a directory in File Explorer as thumbnails?

Tags: windows, winapi, directory, windows-shell, windows-explorer

In a Delphi 10.4.2 win-32 VCL Application in Windows 10, I show the content of a directory in Windows File Explorer using this code and passing a path e.g. `C:\MyDirectory\`:

```
procedure ShellOpen(const Url: string; const Params: string = '');
begin
  Winapi.ShellAPI.ShellExecute(0, 'Open', PChar(Url), PChar(Params), nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
end;
```

This works. But how can I force Explorer to show the files in this directory using THUMBNAILS? Are there any parameters for this that I could use in this procedure?

I have searched a lot for this but did not find anything.

Comment: You can open the window, find it programmatically (maybe using [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=38393) approach) and then obtain a `IFolderView` interface and use its [`IFolderView::SetCurrentViewMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifolderview-setcurrentviewmode) method.

Comment: By the way, this is a very non-trivial question related to the Windows Shell, so you might want to remove the Delphi references. The solution will be the same in any native language (C, C++, Rust, Go, Pascal, Delphi, ...).

Comment: I added a few tags so your question are more likely to get some attention from all Win32 experts.

Comment: Go is not a native programming language. It's lacking in the deterministic destruction department. Quite important with COM, where resource management needs to follow a strict protocol.

Comment: Or rather, Go is not systems programming language. Its reliance on Green Threading makes it a poor fit for a system based on native threads, like COM. So, yes, any of the aforementioned languages will do just fine, except for Go.

Comment: @IInspectable: As you can see, I am not a Go expert! Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the [IFolderView::SetCurrentViewMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifolderview-setcurrentviewmode) method.

Here is a C++ (using Visual Studio's ATL) example:

```
int main()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    {
        // get a shell item
        CComPtr<IShellItem> folder;
        ATLASSERT(SUCCEEDED(SHCreateItemFromParsingName(L"c:\\myPath1\myPath2", nullptr, IID_PPV_ARGS(&folder))));

        // get its PIDL
        CComHeapPtr<ITEMIDLIST> pidl;
        ATLASSERT(SUCCEEDED(CComQIPtr<IPersistIDList>(folder)->GetIDList(&pidl)));

        // open the item
        SHELLEXECUTEINFO info = { };
        info.cbSize = sizeof(info);
        info.fMask = SEE_MASK_IDLIST;
        info.nShow = SW_SHOW;
        info.lpIDList = pidl;
        ATLASSERT(ShellExecuteEx(&info));

        // build a variant from the PIDL
        UINT size = ILGetSize(pidl);
        SAFEARRAY* psa = SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_UI1, 0, size);
        CopyMemory(psa->pvData, pidl, size);
        CComVariant v;
        v.parray = psa;
        v.vt = VT_ARRAY | VT_UI1;

        // find the opened window
        CComPtr<IShellWindows> windows;
        ATLASSERT(SUCCEEDED(windows.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellWindows)));

        CComVariant empty;
        long hwnd;
        CComPtr<IDispatch> disp;
        do
        {
            windows->FindWindowSW(&v, &empty, SWC_BROWSER, &hwnd, SWFO_NEEDDISPATCH, &disp);
            if (disp)
                break;

            // we sleep for a while but using events would be better
            // see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59974072/403671
            Sleep(500);
        } while (true);

        // get IFolderView
        CComPtr<IFolderView> view;
        ATLASSERT(SUCCEEDED(IUnknown_QueryService(disp, IID_IFolderView, IID_PPV_ARGS(&view))));

        // change view mode
        ATLASSERT(SUCCEEDED(view->SetCurrentViewMode(FOLDERVIEWMODE::FVM_THUMBNAIL)));
    }

    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a risk of an infinite loop here if `disp` is never set to a non-NULL value? Still, this seems like a very straight-forward approach -- I'll try it when I get back home tonight.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand - In theory it could, yes, this is sample code, you could add a cumulated max timeout.

Comment: Using the technique from [Do you know when your destructors run? Part 1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040520-00/?p=39243) allows you to drop a level of nesting. @and You're going to have to blame Alan Turing for proving that a general solution to the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) cannot exist.

Comment: @IInspectable - yes, thanks, I know all of Raymond's work, but I'm always lazy to copy back this CCoInitialize code, and I find nesting/scoping quite practical for lots of other reasons, including avoiding dependencies when writing sample code

Comment: Fair enough, particularly with this RAII helper, as I've never found a way to silence the compiler's *"unused variable"* warning. Maybe I just never picked the right spot to drop the [`[[maybe_unused]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused) attribute.

Comment: I just implemented this in Delphi and can confirm that it works well. (+1)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand - you should add your code as an answer too

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Delphi version of the [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67555020/282848) given by [Simon Mourier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403671/simon-mourier):

```pascal
uses
  ComObj, ShellAPI, ShlObj, ActiveX, SHDocVw, ShLwApi;

function IUnknown_QueryService(punk: IUnknown; const guidService: TGUID;
  const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HRESULT; stdcall; external 'ShLwApi'
  name 'IUnknown_QueryService';

type
  TFolderViewMode = (fvmAuto, fvmIcon, fvmSmallIcon, fvmList, fvmDetails,
    fvmThumbnail, fvmTile, fvmThumbstrip, fvmContent);

procedure OpenFolder(AHandle: HWND; const AFolder: string; AViewMode: TFolderViewMode);
const
  FolderViewModes: array[TFolderViewMode] of Cardinal =
    (Cardinal(FVM_AUTO), FVM_ICON, FVM_SMALLICON, FVM_LIST, FVM_DETAILS,
     FVM_THUMBNAIL, FVM_TILE, FVM_THUMBSTRIP, FVM_CONTENT);
var
  ShellItem: IShellItem;
  PIDL: PItemIDList;
  SEInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;
  ILSize: Cardinal;
  SafeArray: PSafeArray;
  v: OleVariant;
  ShellWindows: IShellWindows;
  ExplorerHWND: Integer;
  disp: IDispatch;
  view: IFolderView;
  dummy: OleVariant;
begin

  OleCheck(CoInitialize(nil));
  try

    OleCheck(SHCreateItemFromParsingName(PChar(AFolder), nil, IShellItem, ShellItem));
    try

      OleCheck((ShellItem as IPersistIDList).GetIDList(PIDL));
      try

        ZeroMemory(@SEInfo, SizeOf(SEInfo));
        SEInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(SEInfo);
        SEInfo.Wnd := AHandle;
        SEInfo.fMask := SEE_MASK_IDLIST;
        SEInfo.nShow := SW_SHOW;
        SEInfo.lpIDList := PIDL;
        Win32Check(ShellExecuteEx(@SEInfo));

        ILSize := ILGetSize(PIDL);
        SafeArray := SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_UI1, 0, ILSize);

        CopyMemory(SafeArray.pvData, PIDL, ILSize);
        PVariantArg(@v).vt := VT_ARRAY or VT_UI1;
        PVariantArg(@v).parray := SafeArray;

        OleCheck(CoCreateInstance(CLASS_ShellWindows, nil, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
          IShellWindows, ShellWindows));
        try
          dummy := Unassigned;
          var c: Integer := 0;
          repeat
            if c > 0 then
              Sleep(200);
            disp := ShellWindows.FindWindowSW(v, dummy, SWC_BROWSER, ExplorerHWND,
              SWFO_NEEDDISPATCH);
            Inc(c);
          until Assigned(disp) or (c > 15);
          if disp = nil then
            Exit;
          OleCheck(IUnknown_QueryService(disp, IFolderView, IFolderView, view));
          try
            OleCheck(view.SetCurrentViewMode(FolderViewModes[AViewMode]));
          finally
            view := nil;
          end;
        finally
          ShellWindows := nil;
        end;

      finally
        CoTaskMemFree(PIDL);
      end;

    finally
      ShellItem := nil;
    end;

  finally
    CoUninitialize;
  end;

end;
```

Instead of sleep-polling indefinitely for the window (and potentially killing the application!), I give up after 3 seconds.

Example usage:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OpenFolder(Handle, 'C:\Users\Andreas Rejbrand\Skrivbord\Test', fvmThumbnail);
end;
```

The view modes,

```pascal
type
  TFolderViewMode = (fvmAuto, fvmIcon, fvmSmallIcon, fvmList, fvmDetails,
    fvmThumbnail, fvmTile, fvmThumbstrip, fvmContent);
```

are mapped directly to Windows' [`FOLDERVIEWMODE`s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/ne-shobjidl_core-folderviewmode). Please note that your version of Windows might not support all of them.

Answer (score 0):

No, EXPLORER.EXE has no parameter for this - it [neither had one in *Windows 7*, nor does it have one in *Windows 10*](https://superuser.com/a/1649372/650342). There are surprisingly few parameters available anyway.

Your best bet is starting the Explorer thru [`CreateProcessW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) to then [obtain the handle of its main thread and finally find the new window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13455343/4299358). Then you can manipulate individual controls, such as the file list. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38323255/4299358), based on [AutoIt: Automating Windows Explorer](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/162905-automating-windows-explorer/) - it basically uses `IShellBrowser` and (beyond *Windows XP*) [`IFolderView2.SetViewModeAndIconSize()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifolderview2-setviewmodeandiconsize) to then apply `FVM_THUMBNAIL`.

Comment: That's not how you monitor creation of an Explorer window. See [A big little program: Monitoring Internet Explorer and Explorer windows, part 1: Enumeration](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130610-00/?p=4133), [A big little program: Monitoring Internet Explorer and Explorer windows, part 2: Tracking navigations](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130613-00/?p=4093), and [A big little program: Monitoring Internet Explorer and Explorer windows, part 3: Tracking creation and destruction](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130614-00/?p=4083).